# How to Transfer the .xls file to other FTP Path using C#

Tags: c#

I am new to the C#, I need to transfer .xlx file from specified location to FTP path (\ServerHostName\ExtractedFile). using C# code, Could you please help me

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN page for `FtpWebRequest` contains a few examples dealing with FTP in C# & .NET. One of the examples is exactly what you would like to do, uploading a file. This example is asynchronous.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

On another page, there is a simpler example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks a lot for your response,basically I want to know , How to transfer C:\xx.xls file remote server 10.67.187.88/FileLocation.

Could you please help me

Comment: You just have to replace the server, username/password, local and remote file names in the code above with your information.